# Bounded above/below infinite product of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. The set $$H =\left\{(g_i) \in \prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}G ~|~ \text{ there exists } N \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } g_i = 0 \text{ for all } i \le N \right\}$$
is a subgroup of $\prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}G$. Does it have a name or standard notation?

Comment: That is not a subgroup of $G$. Observe, for example, that this group has the power of the continuum if $G$ is any finite non-trivial group.

Comment: @Pipicito Sorry, typo. I fixed it.

Comment: What about $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}G\times \bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}}G$ ?

Comment: It's vaguely reminiscent of cofiniteness I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This question turned out to be really simple. I am posting Dietrich Burde's observation in the comments as an answer.

There is a group isomorphism $f \colon H \to \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}G \times \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}}G$ given by $f(g_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}= ((g_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}},(g_{-1-i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}})$ for all $(g_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \in \prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}G$.